# How to parse out links and img src references from body copy?

Tags: 7, migrations

I need to modify links and img references in the body of nodes and comments. MPD already gave me good [advice](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21122/how-to-replace-links-and-embedded-image-references-after-migrating-of-content) regarding using a script.

Is there an easy way in Drupal or PHP to parse out all the links in the body copy?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's never easy to do something like this because parsing HTML is a bit hit-and-miss, depending on how well formatted the input is.

I've always found the best way to do it is to load the HTML into a [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) object, loop through and change whatever element attributes/values I need to, then use the `DOMDocument` to give me the new output.

This is a very rough example but hopefully it'll give you the idea:

```
$html = '
  <p>Blah blah blah</p>
  <p><a href="/some-path" title="A Title">Link Text</a>
  </p><p><img src="/some-path.jpg" alt="Some alt" /></p>';

$doc = new DOMDocument;

// This is a reasonable use of the @ operator as malformed HTML will produce
// a lot of warnings. Please don't shoot me ;)
@$doc->loadHTML($html); 

// Get the links.
$links = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($links as $link) {
  // Change the value of an attribute based on the current value.
  if ($link->getAttribute('href') == '/some-path') {
    $link->setAttribute('href', '/some-other-path');
  }
}

// Get the images.
$images = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
  // Change the value of an attribute based on the current value.
  if ($image->getAttribute('src') == '/some-path.jpg') {
    $image->setAttribute('src', '/some-other-path.jpg');
  }
}

// Get the new HTML
$new_html = $doc->saveHTML();

// Strip out the tags that loadHTML() introduces to get the clean HTML.
$patterns = array("/^\<\!DOCTYPE.*?<html><body>/si", "!</body></html>$!si");
$body_text = preg_replace($patterns, '', $new_html);

// Update the node body.
$node->body[$node->language][0]['value'] = $body_text;
```

**EDIT**

I knew I'd seen a good question about this on SO; have a look at [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php) for a good discussion on the subject in general.

Comment: This answer was quite helpful though when using different language based site. In my case 'Malayalam' the end result was was not UTF-8 based but Latin based. I searched a little more to solve this and replaced some lines as: `$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));` and `$node->body[$node->language][0]['value'] = html_entity_decode($body_text);`. My purpose was to convert inner images to base64 code. Thank You @clive

Answer (score 1):

As I answered in your [other question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21122/how-to-replace-links-and-embedded-image-references-after-migrating-of-content), filters are the proper solution since they won't actually alter the data, but the output. This means that should you want to change it differently (or fix a conversion bug), data is still there.

Just check the documentation on [hook_filter_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21filter%21filter.api.php/function/hook_filter_info/7) and have a good time parsing HTML with PHP.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you are not looking at the good way.

Have you try to make a replace in the database?

```
update TABLE_NAME set FIELD_NAME = replace(FIELD_NAME, 'find this string', 'replace found string with this string');

update client_table set company_name = replace(company_name, 'Old Company', 'New Company')
```

I have use use them for some migrations. It's no easy—you must check and map all the replace—but it works.